# Does iOS 8.3 break audio line out over lightning cable?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a charger in my car that also has an audio line out (I've used a gsm iPhone 5 with this, currently I use a cdma iPhone 5s ).  For the past several years it has worked great.  I connect the audio out to my car stereo, and connect the lightning cable to my phone.  My phone then charges and plays audio to the car simultaneously.  After updating to 8.3 the phone will only play out of its tiny speaker which is not really audible while driving.

I've tried a "Reset All Settings", and power cycled many times.  I've tried several different audio playing apps.  The tell tale thing I've noticed is that in the past when I connected the device, the audio volume "goes away" because iPhone audio *line out* doesn't have any volume adjustment option.  Now when I plug in the lightning cable, the volume option never goes away.

I'm considering purchasing bluetooth audio or other solutions, but I'd really like this to just work like it has for years!  Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

--

I realized I have an iPad2 which can also connect to my car audio/charger, and it properly plays audio, and it updated to iOS 8.3?!  Unfortunately there is a hardware difference, because my car charger is the old school 30pin connecter, so it could be that my 30pin to lightning adapter died at the same time iOS 8.3 came out?

Comment: You might just try cleaning the phones connector.  If there is an apple store near see if it works with another device.

Comment: This setup doesn't use the phones connector on the iPhone ( nor with iPad )... The audio goes out the lightning cable.... Well it used to ;-)

Comment: @Tyson Hah, so reading this again in the morning, I'm guessing you meant the (tele)phones (lightning) connector rather than the (head)phones connector.  Well, I've taken alcohol to the lightning connector and no love.   Thanks for the suggestion, Im gonna try and make a trip to the apple store today and see what they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  Turns out my lightning adapter partially broke the same day I installed iOS 8.3  I went to the apple store with the adapter and they offered a free exchange for a new one, replaced, and there was once again the sound of podcasts in my car :-)